# Remove SharePoint Site with Remove-PnPTenantSite in PowerShell not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365

I want to Remove a SharePoint Site via PowerShell by using `Remove-PnPTenantSite`.
This is not working because my Site is still part of an Office 365-Group and i have to delete that first.
To delete the Office 365-Group i have to get the Unified Group.
I tried to use `Get-PnPUnifiedGroup`, but that throws this:

```
Get-PnPUnifiedGroup : Exception while invoking endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/TOKEN/oauth2/token.
```

It would already help to get one of this two Methods to work,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create an app with the Microsoft-Graph-Api permissions, connect pnp online with the app credentials, then delete the unified Group , connect with the normal credentials and then delete the site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -AppId AppID -AppSecret AppSecret -AADDomain Domain
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $cred
Remove-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity Title
Remove-PnPTenantSite Url -Force
```

Comment: The command "Remove-PnPUnifiedGroup" is not available now. Tried to remove the group using "Remove-PnPGroup" and it getting removed, but then executing the command "Remove-PnPTenantSite" is not working though.

Comment: Remove-PnPUnifiedGroup might have been renamed to Remove-PnPMicrosoft365Group in newer PnP versions. But not 100% sure.